# Export starred messages

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

There is a way to export all the event of chat group, but can we have same thing for starred messages also?

As we cannot copy single-single message if we have more number of starred message, we can export those messages in some txt or csv or excel file.

Generaly i starred all those links and messages which contains links of various programming libraries in my chat group, so if there is any way to export it, that will be usefull for everyone.

[image]

As you can see there is only one **export** link which is for events.

Comment: Hm, kindof weird that there's a export function for _events_ on the _stars_ page...

Comment: What do you intend to do with the summarised information?

Comment: Very useful kind of things

Comment: It would be nice if we had the actual model available within data.stackexchange.com so we could run some TSQL queries.